# How to parse google search results in android code

Tags: java, android, parsing

Greetings!
What is the most common way to parse the results of the google search, and turn this:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "region": "IL", 
            "streetAddress": "1611 South Randall Road", 
            "titleNoFormatting": "Brunswick Zone XL Randall Road", 
            "staticMapUrl": "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?maptype=roadmap&format=gif&sensor=false&size=150x100&zoom=13&markers=42.162958,-88.334155", 
            "listingType": "local", 
            "addressLines": [
                "1611 South Randall Road", 
                "Algonquin, IL"
            ], 
            "lng": "-88.334155", 
            "phoneNumbers": [
                {
                    "type": "", 
                    "number": "(847) 658-2257"
                }
            ], 
            "url": "http://www.google.com/maps/place?source=uds&q=brunswick+zone&cid=8286591317090502839", 
            "country": "United States", 
            "city": "Algonquin", 
            "content": "", 
            "GsearchResultClass": "GlocalSearch", 
            "maxAge": 604800, 
            "title": "Brunswick Zone XL Randall"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

into this:

```
Name="Brunswick Zone XL Randall Road"
Address="1611 South Randall Road"
Phone="(847) 658-2257"
```

Answer (score 5):

More generally, do you mean the best way to parse JSON into Java objects? Android's [org.json](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) parser, at least for general-purpose DOM-style parsing. It's reasonably fast on small data sets and comes built in to the OS.